# Draw Flag as Overlay on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to draw a country's flag on top of country boundary. I am using the coordinate data from [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries)

The way I am adding overlay is

```
[mapView addOverlays:countryName];
```

Then rendering it as

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
  {
    MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];
    renderer.fillColor      = [ColorUtil colorFromHexString:@"#EE5A43" withAlpha:0.6];
    renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];
    renderer.lineWidth   = 2;
    return renderer;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Now my idea was to draw the overlay with the flag. So I subclasses MKPolygonRenderer and added

```
@implementation MyMKOverlayRenderer
- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay overlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage {
  self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];
  if (self) {
    _overlayImage = overlayImage;
  }

  return self;
}
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
  CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;

  MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
  CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

  CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
  CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
@end
```

Now check the two attached images. I was expecting the flag to be inside the boundary of the polygon. But looks like it is not happening. So may be my approach is wrong. Can some expert help me in correct direction.

[image: without drawing flag]

[image: drawing flag]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The key was to create a UIBezierPath and clip the overlay image.

I have posted the entire solution [here](http://iosrecipe.blogspot.com/2015/12/drawing-flag-as-overlay-on-top-of.html)

Now it looks like

[image]